# Windows dark themed with autocomplete Tex editor?

Tags: windows, editor, latex, dark-theme

I have been trying different editors, but I always find that they are lacking some of the traditional code editors' features.

The only one I have found that could fit the requirements of being dark themed and having autocomplete was **Atom** with the respective packages, but the result didn't feel good.

Is there any dark themed editor with autocomplete function for Windows that you find works ok?

Comment: Related: [list of LaTeX editors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) and [dark theme for TeXstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texstudio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TexStudio with a dark theme works great. Here is another thread where how to set TexStudio with a dark themed like Scholarized can be performed:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texstudio

Answer (score 0):

You could use Microsoft Visual Studio Code with a LaTeX plugin

LaTex plugins:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=latex&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance

Or more specifically this plugin:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop

and for themes you can choose from a plethora of dark themes:
For example OneDark
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=akamud.vscode-theme-onedark

[image]

Comment: But wouldn't that be just the same as using Atom with extra steps?

Comment: @DanielDíez I am sorry I haven't used Atom, except once or twice for a few minutes, so I can't comment on that. You can give it a try with VS Code, it might work for you better than Atom :)